# How to add pandas text column one below other

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, text

I want the 3 input columns in pandas dataframe columns like pros, cons and sentiment which are text columns

```
pros| cons |sentiment
_________________________
text| text | positive
text| text | negative
```

i want to the columns to be like

```
review|sentiment               
________________
pros|positive                   
pros|positive                     
pros|positive                   
pros|positive                  
cons|negative             
cons|negative               
cons|negative
```

I would like to have a new column review which has the pro columns text with its sentiment value, below that the text of cons with their sentiment value
How to arrange the initial dataframe to the review and sentiment column in pandas?

Comment: post a testable df sample and expected result to it

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

Assuming `df` is your dataframe :

```
out = (
       df.melt(id_vars="sentiment",
               value_vars=["pros", "cons"],
               value_name="review")
        .sort_values(by="sentiment", ascending=False)
        [['review', 'sentiment']]
      )
​
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  review sentiment
0   text  positive
2   text  positive
1   text  negative
3   text  negative
```